# how do i get the value of self into the normal Variable

Tags: ios, function, variables, self

how can i get the value of self.valve1 from function readFireBaseData() into the function viewDidload() ??? i always get the set value of "valve1" which i set at the begining of the program. Hope someone can help me.

```
    import UIKit
    import FirebaseDatabase
    import Firebase

    class ValveViewController: UIViewController {

    var valve1    = "OFF"
    @IBOutlet var valveOne:     UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        readFirebaseData() //run the function readFireBaseData
        let toggle = view.viewWithTag(1) as! UISwitch

        if valve1 == "ON"
        {
            toggle.setOn(true, animated: true)
        }else
        {
            toggle.setOn(false, animated: true)
        }
         super.viewDidLoad()
    }//END of viewDidLoad

    func readFirebaseData(){

        var ref: DatabaseReference!
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("switchValve").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

            self.valve1 = value?["valveOne"]    as? String ?? ""
        })  
    }//End of readFireBaseData
}//End of ViewController
```

Comment: The data is going to be retrieved from Firebase asynchronously.  You need to access the value after it has been set in the closure.  Typically you would pass a closure to `readFirebaseData` and have the function invoke that once the data has been retrieved

Comment: how can i wait in the function readFireBaseData() until the request was succesfull?? i read a lot of completionHandler but i have no idea how to handle with completionHandler.

Comment: You can't wait (or rather you shouldn't). If you are going to,program for iOS you need to learn about asynchronous execution and the use of completion handlers.